# File locking in Python with fcntl

Tags: python, exception, locking, fcntl

I am trying to define functions to ease the locking of files with the fcntl module. When I manually run

```
fcntl.lockf(lock_file, fcntl.LOCK_EX | fcntl.LOCK_NB)
```

in two separate instances of Python, I get the expected exception

```
BlockingIOError: [Errno 11] Resource temporarily unavailable
```

but when I define functions to automate this in `mylock.py`:

```
import fcntl

def lock(filepath):
    lock_file = open(filepath, "a")
    try:
        fcntl.lockf(lock_file, fcntl.LOCK_EX | fcntl.LOCK_NB)
    except OSError or BlockingIOError:
        return False
    return True

def unlock(filepath):
    lock_file = open(filepath, "a")
    try:
        fcntl.lockf(lock_file, fcntl.LOCK_UN)
    except OSError or BlockingIOError:
        return False
    return True
```

and then import this into two separate python instances and do

```
mylock.lock("test.txt")
```

which unexpectedly returns `True` in both instances. Is my error handling inappropriate? I have also tried `except IOError:`, `except Exception:` and `except:` -- I don't understand why the BlockingIOError raised when I run the fcntl commands in isolation doesn't cause the `except` logic to be executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the problem seems to have been that the file was being garbage collected, since the handle `lock_file` was not being used after the function. If the `return` statement is modified to `return lock_file` then the desired behaviour is achieved.